# "Fatal: there are problems with fetch_image.cgi" using LabelMeAnnotationTool

Tags: linux, error-handling, annotations, label, apache2

When i link to http://server@jdijfowjofd/LabelMeAnnotationTool/tool.html, I got an error

```
Fatal: there are problems with fetch_image.cgi.
```

Using the address http://server@jdijfowjofd/LabelMeAnnotationTool/tool.html?collection=LabelMe&mode=i&folder=null&image=null, its with null folder and image null

How do I remove this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/CSAILVision/LabelMeAnnotationTool/issues/45 (*Fatal: there are problems with fetch_image.cgi*) for a similar discussion of this topic.

From your side errorlog is required to distinguish the cause and resolve, but the most general solution is

> sudo apt-get install libcgi-session-perl